# Accessing dimensions of SVG component in Aurelia

Tags: d3.js, aurelia

I'm porting over a d3 application into Aurelia and need to access the width and height of the chart's SVG parent in order to fit the chart properly to the current screen dimensions.

Before porting, it looked like this, filling up the whole container properly:

[image: Should look like this, filling up entire container]

This is what it looks like in Aurelia:

[image: Looks like this in Aurelia]

It sets its dimensions by calling `d3.select('#timeline-svg').style('width')` and `d3.select('#timeline-svg').style('height')`.  But now, in Aurelia, whenever I call those it returns dimensions of 300 x 150, no matter what the dimensions of the SVG actually are.  I tried calling the same code on the SVG's div parent (which has identical dimensions) and that didn't help either.

So then I thought to try two-way data binding and changed my SVG tag to `<svg id="timeline-svg" width.two-way="width"></svg>` (and declared a corresponding `width` variable in my view-model), but I get the error: `Error: Observation of a "svg" element's "width" property is not supported.`

I've even tried using `aurelia-pal`, injecting it as `DOM` and calling:

`attached() {console.log(this.DOM.getElementById("timeline-svg").style.width);}` but all that gives me is an empty string.

There's a gist [here](https://gist.run/?id=bb7f31730fff57cbafc0559485e012bb) (minus the d3 code, but all I want to figure out is how to access the dimensions of the SVG element in app.html from within app.js). What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You almost certainly don't want the # when you call getElementById

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  That resolves the TypeError, but now that log statement just returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you could use the `ref` custom attribute to get a reference the svg element itself.

```
<svg ref="svgElement"></svg>
```

Then use the `getBBox()` function. The result of that function will have a `width` property you can use.

```
this.svgElement.getBBox().width
```

Here's a simple gist example: https://gist.run/?id=0ed86f511533512a22d002675221d812

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it prints out `BBox SVGRect { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }`, even though I called the log statement from `attached()` after the plot itself is rendered from within the SVG (meaning there's no way the SVG could have dimension 0x0 at that point).  I don't get it.  It must be an Aurelia-specific issue that I'm not understanding.

Comment: Would you mind creating a gist example showing the issue? I'll try to figure out the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the offer!  I put together a minimal example gist [here](https://gist.run/?id=bb7f31730fff57cbafc0559485e012bb).  It doesn't involve any d3 because that really has nothing to do with it.  All I'm trying to do is find out how to access the dimensions of the single SVG element (the white box in the bottom left of the layout) in app.html from within my app.js class.

Comment: You need to have content in the SVG element before it's bounding box will report any size: https://gist.run/?id=c303fa0f0516cade76e5108bfc69c59e

Comment: But as [this gist](https://gist.run/?id=5b4556fcac9fc5b409dbd92d35a413a9) shows, I can find the dimensions of an empty SVG just fine when _not_ using Aurelia.  But when running (what appears to me) to be the same exact code from within Aurelia (in [this gist](https://gist.run/?id=0a2e9d0ff056a032f3c74336c5edebc5)), the dimensions returned are always 300x150, no matter what you resize the window (and therefore the SVG) to.