# SystemJS can't load aurelia-event-aggregator even though Aurelia has already loaded it

Tags: aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I'm simply trying to import 'aurelia-event-aggregator' into a TypeScript class and I get this error in my console.  Even though it says it's loaded and configured aurelia-event-aggregator on lines 5 & 6, it says SystemJS still can't find it.  This is especially strange since I'm also (successfully) importing autoinject from 'aurelia-dependency-injection' and customElement from 'aurelia-framework' without a problem, and they seem to be configured/installed identically to the event aggregator on my system via jspm.

My config.js and package.json are [here](https://gist.github.com/davidlav/0da0254f6cab72cc6148e28f70f5a459).

I haven't the slightest idea how to start troubleshooting this.  Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to sound dumb, but you need to run `jspm install aurelia-event-aggregator`. I know it's already in your project, but jspm 0.16 doesn't support peer dependencies (at least that's what I remember), so you have to explicitly install it as a top level dep for your app and then it will start working.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!  I don't mean to be off topic, but I replied back to a suggestion you had for me on [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271897/accessing-dimensions-of-svg-component-in-aurelia/40272278?noredirect=1#comment67849255_40272278) the other day that I still haven't been able to resolve.  I linked to two gists in that comment that hightlight the problem and was hoping maybe there was as simple an answer for that question as there was for this.  Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry about that. I've been at DevIntersection this week and had two talks yesterday and taught a workshop today. I just boarded my first leg of my flights home. I'll do my best to get back to you tomorrow or Monday. It might be a bug in Aurelia though.

Comment: I totally understand. Have a safe flight and thanks again!

Comment: @AshleyGrant I could solve this problem by declaring aurelia-event-aggregator in the config.js, without running jspm install. Running jspm install also works because it downloads the lib and generates the missing line.

Comment: @FabioLuz I don't recommend hand-editing config.js as JSPM can overwrite that file at any time, and also sometimes the only way to make JSPM behave itself is to completely delete the `map` section of the config.js. I have had clients insist on editing it by hand, and invariably it has caused them headaches at later dates.

Comment: @AshleyGrant hmmm that's good to know! I'll not hand-edit config.js anymore. Thank you!